# Filter Events with collections

Tags: javascript, html, mongodb, meteor

I have projects and workflows with separate collections.

```
collections:
Project = new Meteor.Collection("project");
Workflow = new Meteor.Collection("workflow");
```

After creating project, I am selecting project in the form and displaying Work flow card.

```
HTML:
<!-- Workflow Card -->


  <div id="wCard">

                {{#each workflow}}

                **<div class="pheader">
                     <h2>{{project}}</h2>
                     <hr width="100%">
                </div>**

                     <br>
                 <div class="workflowcard">
                 <div class="module-card">
                     <div class="card-header wfmodule">{{workflowTitle}}</div>
                   <div class="casting">
                    <div class="assigned-tag">Assigned To:</div>
                    <div class="assigned-to">{{team}}<hr></div>
                    <div class="actions">No Actions Created</div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="due">

                       Due on:

                        <div>
                            <div class="day-stamp" >{{weekday d_date}}</div>
                        <div class="date-stamp">{{date d_date}}</div>
                        <div class="month-stamp">{{month d_date}}</div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
              <div class="btn-box showmuloption">
      <button type="edit" class="editw"  style="display:none">Edit Workflow</button>
      <button type="hide" class="hidew"  style="display:none">Hide Actions</button>
      <div class="actionBtn"><button class="btn-wf stage-blue-wf button-x-small-wf" id="newAction">New Action</button></div>

    </div>
            </div>
                {{/each}}
        </div>  

.JS:



Template.workflow.helpers({
    getWorkflow: function(){
        return Workflow.find();
    },
    user: function(){
 return  Meteor.users.find({});
 },
 getNewaction: function(){
        return Newaction.find();
    },

});
```

Now the workflow cards are displaying in a list. I want to display workflows according to projects. If I select a project, the workflow should go to that project, and I create another workflow with same project, it should display in that project. And if I select another project, the workflow should display in that related project.

Please help through this.

Comment: Please share helpers as well. Just a query- YOu have wrapped the html in `template` tags; Right?

Comment: I have shared the helpers. Yes I have wrapped the html code in template.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use reactive varrible for this.
At first you need add meteor package:

```
$ meteor add reactive-var
```

Your form with project selecting might look like this:

```
<select id="project" value="{{getProject}}">
   {{#each getProjectsList}}
      <option id='{{_id}}' value="{{_id}}">{{projectname}}</option>
   {{/each}}
</select>
```

Don't forget create helpers `getProject` and `getProjectsList`.
Now it's time for reactive varrible, you can initialise this in `onCreated` event.

```
Template.workflow.onCreated(function() {
   var instance = this;
   instance.projectId = new ReactiveVar(null);
});
```

When you change selected project, you should change you reactive varrible.

```
Template.workflow.events({
   'change #project': function(){
      Template.instance().projectId.set($("#project").val());
});
```

Every workflow need to have field with project id. You get workflows list like this

`{{#each getWorkflows}}`

And there is helper for getting workflow's list:

```
Template.workflow.helpers({
    getWorkflows: function() {
       var id = Template.instance().projectId.get();
       return Workflow.find({projectId: id});
    },

    ...// another helpers

})
```

So, when you will change project in form, list of workflow also will change, because it depends on reactive var. Also you can sibscribe only needed workflow object, and not all collection.
I hope this will helpfull to someone.

Comment: This looks like useful. Thanks for your response.

Comment: {{#each workflow}}
                <div class="pheader">
                     <h2>{{project}}</h2>
                     <hr width="100%">
                </div>                                                                                                                I am calling my project name in my form like this. As I mentioned in HTML page.And I did not use project list. So how can I use as my form Id's. Please provide a solution for how to write in form and call Id's.

Comment: If i understand you correctly, you need get workflows list by projectname. If so, you may enter name in your edit form, then find project id with such name like Project.findOne({projectname:$(#nameFromForm).val})._id; and put it in reactive varrible, your workflow halper should work as well. Sorry, if I am wrong.

Comment: This information is very helpful.Thank u Victor. I am very glad if I know how  to create helpers for 'getProject' and 'getProjectList'? If I can write helpers, it may work to filter workflows.

Comment: @keerthi `getProject:function(){return Projects.findOne()}` it need for some default value in select list. `getProjectList:function(){return Projects.find()}` just return all of available projects. Also you can sort projects by name, like this `getProjectList:function(){return Projects.find({},{sort:{projectname:1}})}`

Comment: It seems to be we are on same track. But I could not sort projects in code.  If we can contact through mail, we can get better result. I am sharing my mail ID. "prashanteja@gmail.com". Kindly please provide your mail ID. So that we can have a clear discussion.